# How does onchange carry selected text and hidden value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events

I have a dynamically populated PHP dropdown menu that gathers the following information from the database:

```
echo '<option value="'.$image['id'].'">'.$image['description'].'</option>';
```

I then have a JavaScript function that shows the selected text - description in an input box for editing and then on submit update back into the database.

**Question**:  Is there away using JavaScript that I could pass the **id** and **description** together but only have the description show in the input box for editing?

```
$('#captionSelect').change(function(){
        $('#captionInput').val($("#captionSelect option:selected").text()).show();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

```
$('#captionSelect').change(function(){
        $('#captionInput').val($("#captionSelect option:selected").html()).show();
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hello jess Try this out....

```
 $('#captionSelect').change(function(){
            $('#captionInput').val($("#captionSelect").val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a hidden form field to your form.

Then you can use:

```
$('#captionSelect').change(function(){
    var $selected = $("#captionSelect option:selected");
    $('#hiddenField').val($selected.val());
    $('#captionInput').val($selected.text()).show();
});
```

I added the `$selected` to avoid multiple look-ups.